# Module app dependency results in "error: package x does not exist" with experimental gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android NDK based project that uses the experimental gradle plugin. I am trying to add React Native and the [React Native Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) (RNN) module to the project

The example project that comes with RNN builds and runs as expected. However in order to make RNN compatible with my project I had to update its `build.gradle` file to work with the experimental gradle plugin: https://github.com/adamski/react-native-navigation/commit/0a848f574cedae83bf8961bd1fafe8a42e4257cc

I am hitting the following build error:

```
Error:(64, 1) error: package com.reactnativenavigation.activities does not exist
```

I have trawled SO and the web for a solution to this. I can see the project and navigate it in AS:

[image: Android Studio RNN module]

However on navigating to the main Activity java class, it shows red lines where it cannot find the dependency, even though it offers the option if importing the files to the main project(?).

My `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app'
include ':react-native-navigation'
project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/')
```

The project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-rc1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {  // All of React Native (JS, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../../node_modules/react-native/android" // node_modules is two levels up from the AndroidStudio project folder
        }
    }
}
```

The app's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.company.myapp"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "juce_jni"
        toolchain = "clang"
        stl = "c++_static"
        cppFlags.add("-fsigned-char")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-frtti")
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ENABLE_LIVE_CONSTANT_EDITOR=0")
        cppFlags.add("-DJUCER_ANDROIDSTUDIO_4330F05B=1")
        cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_APP_VERSION=0.4.0")
        cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_APP_VERSION_HEX=0x400")
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../Fonts".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../Source".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../iOS".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../../../juce_modules/adamski/PitchDetector/modules".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../Source/LookAndFeel".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../Source/Synth".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../Source/UI".toString())
        ldLibs.add("android")
        ldLibs.add("EGL")
        ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
        ldLibs.add("log")
        platformVersion = 15
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                source {
                    exclude "**/JuceModules/"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            ndk.with {
                debuggable = true
                cppFlags.add("-g")
                cppFlags.add("-DDEBUG=1")
                cppFlags.add("-D_DEBUG=1")
                cppFlags.add("-O0")
                cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../JuceLibraryCode".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../../../JUCE/modules".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../../../juce_modules/adamski".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID=1")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID_API_VERSION=21")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME=com_company_myapp_MyApp")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSPATH=\"com/company/myapp/MyApp\"")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ENABLE_LIVE_CONSTANT_EDITOR=0")
            }
        }
        release {
            signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.releaseConfig")
            ndk.with {
                cppFlags.add("-DNDEBUG=1")
                cppFlags.add("-O3")
                cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../JuceLibraryCode".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../../../JUCE/modules".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-I${project.rootDir}/../../../../juce_modules/adamski".toString())
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID=1")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID_API_VERSION=21")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME=com_company_myapp_MyApp")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ANDROID_ACTIVITY_CLASSPATH=\"com/company/myapp/MyApp\"")
                cppFlags.add("-DJUCE_ENABLE_LIVE_CONSTANT_EDITOR=0")
            }
        }
    }
    android.signingConfigs {
        create("releaseConfig") {
            storeFile = new File("/Users/adamelemental/.android/debug.keystore")
            storePassword = "android"
            keyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword = "android"
            storeType = "jks"
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("armeabi") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("armeabi-v7a") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

    // The following do not work with the experimental gradle plugin:
    //    debugCompile project(path: ':react-native-navigation', configuration: 'libraryDebug')
    //    releaseCompile project(path: ':react-native-navigation', configuration: 'libraryRelease')

    compile project (':react-native-navigation')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the `productFlavors` part of RNN's `build.gradle` got past this issue.